# Rails 4 strong parameters custom require name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters, batman.js

I created an API for my Rails application and I'm using BatmanJs for the front end. When creating a new item, Rails create it but throw me an error `undefined method 'model_name' for TrueClass:Class` associate to :

**items_controller.rb**

```
def create
  @item = current_user.get_items.new( item_params )
  respond_with @item.save  # Apparently come from this line
end
```

I believe it's come from my strong parameters settings. Since I'm using namespace for this API `api/items`, using batman, I also have to specify it in the model :

**item.js.coffee**

```
class App.Item extends Batman.Model
  @resourceName: 'api/items'
  @persist Batman.RailsStorage
```

and then in my controller I have to change the strong parameters according to that since Batman is using `resourceName` as index when posting data :

```
def item_params
  params.require('api/item').permit(
    :name, :address, :postcode, :town, :phone, :email, :department_id, :country_id, :mobile, :fax, :website
  )
end
```

I think my error come from the fact that when Rails try to instanciate a new item, it's tried to use the `api/item` as symbole and can't find an associate model. So my question is, how can I modify on the fly `params.require('api/item').permit` to `params.require(:item).permit` just before instanciate a new item so Rails knows then what to call?

Thanks

**EDIT**
Here is what Batman is sending to Rails :

```
Started POST "/api/items.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-13 11:20:29 +1100
Processing by Api::V1::ItemsController#create as JSON

Parameters: {"api/item"=>{"name"=>"Test item", "address"=>"12 street address", "fax"=>"", "phone"=>"09064521212", "mobile"=>"", "email"=>"contact@test.com", "postcode"=>"64040", "town"=>"Los Angeles", "website"=>"www.test.com", "department_id"=>"2", "country_id"=>"2"}}
```

and here is the query it does right after (in the server log) :

```
(0.5ms)  BEGIN
SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO `items` (`address`, `country_id`, `created_at`, `department_id`, `email`, `fax`, `group_id`, `mobile`, `name`, `phone`, `postcode`, `town`, `updated_at`, `website`) VALUES ('12 street address', 2, '2013-11-13 00:20:29', 2, 'contact@test.com', '', 1, '', 'Test item', '09064521212', '64040', 'Los Angeles', '2013-11-13 00:20:29', 'www.test.com')
(52.7ms)  COMMIT
```

also the error on the server log just after the insertion :

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `model_name' for TrueClass:Class:
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/model_naming.rb:9:in     `model_name_from_record_or_class'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb:182:in `build_named_route_call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb:120:in `polymorphic_url'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:159:in `url_for'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:68:in `_process_options'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:202:in `_process_options'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:32:in `block in _handle_render_options'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:30:in    `_handle_render_options'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:26:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:97:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
```

Comment: I am not familiar with Batmans, can you put the actual request that BatmanJS makes. So it will be a bit clearer to work with.

Comment: this looks right to me, you probably need to write a test for this case and see how it goes.

Comment: Could this be your problem: `require('api/item')` -> what do the parameters look like? It could be messing with Rails' backend to not have a specific name (such as item)

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. Yeah thats the problem i described in my post so i was looking if it was possible to change it on the fly, just after getting params from front end, but before calling save. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys I finally found where that problem came from. I needed to replace :

```
respond_with @item.save
```

by :

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render json: @item.save }
end
```

I still don't understand why it didn't work the first way as they are supposed to be the same. If someone has an explanation, I'll be more than happy to know it :)

Anyway, it's fixed now. Thanks to everyone for your help

Answer (score 0):

Can you mess with the params before calling `#require` ? For example:

```
def item_params
  params[:item] = params["api/item"] if params[:item].blank? && params["item/api"].present?
  item_attrs = [] # <-- your symbols here
  params.require(:item).permit(*item_attrs)
end
```

Comment: well thanks for your answer but it's not working. That was a pretty good idea BTW but I guess the problem might come from somewhere else :(